# Editing user's local files using monaco-editor in a web code editor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, editor, monaco-editor

I'm currently implementing a web editor which takes in a custom language files from a user's local machine and allows the user to edit them.

1. Is it possible to implement a feature which updates the file through the web editor directly (doesn't need the user to save a new file for the changes and updates the file directly)?
2. Is it possible to allow the user to upload folders to the web editor and display them in a file tree format?
3. Is it possible to do all of this client side without a web server?

I have tried to find open source examples of these types of implementations to no avail. Thank you!

Googling for open source projects that creates a web editor with a custom language containing file/folder uploading and editor tabs.

Comment: What you describe here is exactly what VSCode is. The problem is cannot do 1. when you run within a browser, so it has to be an installed app like VSCode. This answer renders 2 irrelvant and answers 3. Yes as you'll end up with an installed app, you can do it without a web server. But if you do that, you have exactly what VS Code is. If you want to run in in the browser you cannot do 1 and you cannot do it without a web server, but 2 is possible. But then you have exactly what [VS Code for the Web](https://vscode.dev/) is.

Comment: I see, it seems there's a lot of limitations to creating that web editor... Truthfully, I had an extension for the language but there were difficulties with installation as our users are not familiar with technology. I am working with a modeling language in systems biology (sort of an obscure language), so the simpler the better. I would probably be better off having the user save a new file after making changes. Thank you for the information!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.